# Airbus Imagery Open Layers 3 WMTS request

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

When using the Airbus WMTS service, my map renders incorrectly.

Here is an image of OSM vs Airbus at the same viewport:

[image: OSM] [image: Airbus]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm assuming it's a projection issue.

This implementation is based on this [official Open Layers Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html)

```
function customTileLoader(tile, src) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', src);
    client.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${api_key}`);

    client.onload = function() {
        const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], { type: 'image/png' });
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        tile.getImage().src = imageUrl;
    };
    client.send();
}
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');
var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
var resolutions = new Array(14);
var matrixIds = new Array(14);
for (var z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
    // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
    resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
    matrixIds[z] = z;
}
const airbus_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: "https://view.geoapi-airbusds.com/api/v1/map/imagery.wmts",
        format: 'image/png',
        request: 'GetTile',
        version: "1.1.1",
        projection: projection,
        wrapX: true,
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
            origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
            resolutions: resolutions,
            matrixIds: matrixIds
        }),
        tileLoadFunction: customTileLoader
    })
})
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        airbus_layer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like your WMTS source may be EPSG:4326.  If you pan to an arctic region and it looks stretched you can confirm that.

Comment: @Mike indeed I can confirm that long stretch in the arctic region. Testing projection changes now

Comment: @Mike - changing the projection to `EPSG:4326` unfortunately did not fix the problem. When looking a Africa on OSM and switching over to Airbus, the view now shows the Eastern region of Northern America.

Comment: I don't have access to the Airbus url wihout a login but the documentation suggests there is also a EPSG:3857 service.  You may need to specify matrixSet or a different url.